# In a method does the pointer or actually object get passed as a parameter?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers, methods

I have been messing around with a bit of code to try and get my head around pointers and memory management in objective-c. However, what I can't seem to understand is that using this code:

```
hello *myHello = [[hello alloc] init];

NSString *string = @"Hello";

myHello.property = string;
```

does the NSString instance (@"Hello") get passed as a parameter to the setter method or does the pointer get sent. For example if I changed "string" to point to a different object and then got the variable would it still be "Hello" or change to the new object that "string" pointed to?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The pointer is copied. So `myHello.property` points to the same place as `string` does (until either of them is changed).

Comment: Thankyou, but when I changed where 'string' pointed to and printed out the variable the same object as before got printed, not the new one? I don't really know what is going on there?

Comment: When you change where `string` points to, you don't change where `myHello.property` points to. That still points to where `string` pointed to when you assigned `myHello.property = string;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
myHello.property = string;
```

If **property** is defined without **copy**, it is set to point to the same place that **string** points to.

If **property** is defined with **copy**, it is set to point to a new copy of the original string.

In either case, if you then change **string** to point to a different string (e.g. @"Goodbye"), **property** will still point to @"Hello".

Comment: Ok thankyou very much, if say you had a pointer that points to another etc... will the pointer passed into the method ultimately still point to the root object?

Comment: @user1628311. No, when you change `string` you are changing it's pointer location to something different. Now property is pointing to one thing, and string is pointing to another. They are not related any more.

Comment: A pointer to a ponter will reflect changes made to the original pointer but you would not want the original pointer to be an automatic variable as is *string* in your example.

Comment: @user1628311, See my visual answer for clearly insight. Sorry Jim. ;)

Comment: This is only true for @properties using strong/retain and weak/assign/unsafe_unretained semantics. If copy is specified, a new object is created by copying the input argument to the property's setter method.

Comment: Thanks everybody everything's finally clicking together!

Comment: This is slightly misleading (though ultimately correct).   Using either `retain` or `copy` (or `assign`,etc), the *same* string will be passed as an argument.  The copy is made inside of the (oft-synthesized) implementation of `setProperty:`.

Answer (score 1):

Jim had a good answer, but I want to add a visual one as it might help people.

Say *string = @"test"

string is pointing to a memory location that stores @"test"

Esentially, it looks like this:

```
      @"test"
        ^
string /
```

When you do:

`myHello.property = string;`

You are just setting property to the same place string was, like this;

```
     @"test"
        ^
string /  \ property
```

Then, if you later change string to say @"hello" You create another location in memory, and keep the other. Now it is like this.

```
      @"hello"  @"test"
        ^         ^
string /           \ property
```

The only way property could be tampered with is if you messed with the pointer. Since that will probably never happen, you don't need to worry about it.

Some newbies think that this will cause memory problems, but it won't. ARC can tell when you are done with property and it will remove the memory itself.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes thanks, I now realise why you have to use copy as well as using a mutable string will change the actual object being pointed to!